# returning list of string items from an array function and avoiding duplicate entry

Tags: c++, arduino-c++

I am newbie to cpp.

```
string* getNames() {
 string* names = new string[3];
 names[0] = "Simon";
 names[1] = "Dave";
 names[2] = "Dave"; 

 return names;
}

value = getNames();
```

value should return `["Simon" , "Dave"]`

What I am trying to achieve is to getting an array with string items but avoiding any duplicate.

However secondly I want if on new iteration runs I want to take out the item that is not present in the new list !

Comment: An array is too stupid to know about duplication. Consider using a [`std::set`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set) if it is available in Arduino's C++ Standard Library implementation.

Comment: that would be brilliant , in python I always use `set` but I do not know how to use `set` in cpp.

Comment: Unless you use something like `std::(unordered_)set<string>` then you will have to search for duplicates manually before adding them to the array, such as with `std::find()`

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set

Comment: No time like the present to learn. I turned `std::set` into [a link to one of the better documentation sites](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set). That site is very precise and complete, but might look like it's written in Martian. If you have trouble understanding it, See if this simpler, less accurate [documentation page](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/set/set/) can help get you started.

Comment: `I am newbie to cpp.` Then you shouldn't be using `new`. It is for experienced users only.

Comment: `string* names = new string[3];` -- There is no need for `new` here.  Just `string names[3];` is all that is needed.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie That would be an automatic variable. Returning a pointer to an automatic variable would be a bad idea.

Comment: OK, I didn't see the return value.  `std::array<std::string, 3> names;` could have been used.

Comment: you guys seem to be ignoring `arduino-c++` tag